# Using like for numeric in a constraint

Tags: sql

I am creating a table which is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Peeps
(
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNum BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PhoneNum_Check CHECK (PhoneNum LIKE '08%')
)
```

Every phone number has to start with `08`. However when I tried insert there's an error because LIKE can't be used for numeric (or that's what my friend said). The alternative would be using `VARCHAR` for `PhoneNum`, but this is an assignment and we have to use numeric for the phone number.

Comment: Can you ever calculate with that phone number? Does "phoneNum+1" make any sense? If not, then it is not a number, but a string that happens to consist of digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a phone number can start with a `0` then you need to use a string:

```
CREATE TABLE Peeps (
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNum VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PhoneNum_Check CHECK (PhoneNum LIKE '08%')
);
```

Although you *can* use `LIKE` on a number, it is highly not recommended.  What happens is that the number is converted to a string.  However, that string will never start with a `0` -- well, at least never when the value is greater than 1.

Comment: I see, thank you. I was just wondering is there any other alternative that still follows the requirement of the assignment